# Make python process stop/wait/sleep for 0.2 seconds [Works]

Tags: python, time, milliseconds

Title says it all, is it possible to make python sleep for less than a second?
WORKS:

```
import time
print ("foo")
time.sleep(0.2) #talking about the value of the time
print ("bar")
```

If not, then is there any other way?
Thanks
Using python 3.2.2
EDIT: Thanks guys, I'm pretty sure I have tried the above code before and it didn't work. Oh well... sorry for your waste if time. It worked now and I upgraded to 3.3

Comment: Have you tried this? This is very valid code. And for the love of all that is computable, please switch to python3.3, which is the stable 3.x release

Comment: Did you actually try this? Your code already works.

Comment: Answer is: "yes", for example see your own code ;-)

Comment: Did you read the [`time.sleep()` documantion](http://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep)? If so, what wasn't clear or match your requirements?

Comment: this is a little complicated: so what you need to do is select the code you put in your question, copy it, paste it into your interactive session or .py file, and run it. voila!

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: The OP may be on a Ubuntu or Debian release which still provides 3.2. It doesn't really matter here.

Comment: No real question here, at least no such question that cannot be answered by interpreter. Downvote for that. And BTW: see comments above, they're helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [usleep in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568646/usleep-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [`time.sleep()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) documentation:

> The actual suspension time **may be less than** that requested because any caught signal will terminate the sleep() following execution of that signal’s catching routine. Also, the suspension time **may be longer than** requested by an arbitrary amount because of the scheduling of other activity in the system.

So it works but there are no guarantees.