# How to implement high precision sleep by using Python?

Tags: python, sleep, usleep

I'm currently doing a research which I need to implement high precision `sleep` function, within 10-100 (`us`) microsecond accuracy, is there has any possible method I can achieve that? I tried to use `time.sleep(50/1000000)`, but it not working.
This code is I tried in my `Mac`,

```
import time

print(time.time())
seconds = 10
time.sleep(seconds/1000000.0)
print(time.time())
```

The accuracy is closer to 1000 us, but I hope to get higher precision.

If `Python` cannot achieve that, is there any other language can achieve that?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5568646/usleep-in-python this should work though.  Can you be more specific on whats not working.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133857/how-accurate-is-pythons-time-sleep, you can not achieve precision in microsecond, but just on millisecond. It's a limitation on OS, you it appears that it is not possible to do that despite of the function you are using.

Comment: Updated, so is there any other language or other OS I can achieve that?

Comment: My guess would be if any language can do it it will be C++ or C

Comment: Baased on @VítorCézar's comment, this really does seem like a hardware limitation that you'll have a hard time getting around just by changing languages. You might find better luck on [superuser](https://superuser.com/), [hardware recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), or another [stackexchange site](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

Comment: just curious - what research are you doing where you need this kind of precision?