# What is the smallest interval one can reliably use with Python's threading.Timer?

Tags: python

Sample code

```
interval = 1e-6
threading.Timer( interval, func ).start()
```

What is the smallest interval one can use **reliably**? Experimentation got me 1e-6, but wondering if there is a precise value.

Comment: I'm sure it depends on your hardware. If you're running Python on a jerry-rigged whose internal clock only runs at 1Hz, Any interval smaller than `1` obviously won't work :)

Answer (score 0):

It is completely dependent on the OS and python implementation. Generally, you shouldn't expect timer to be high precision. [Windows has around a 10-13 ms sleep resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133857/how-accurate-is-pythons-time-sleep) and I expect it to be a similar case for threading.Timer().