# how to optimize script to have 1 second between spoken words using speech module

Tags: python, python-2.7, sleep, text-to-speech, speech

the problem is that when i run my script it takes longer than the expected time 1 second before it says the next command. i think this has something to do with the speech command. what can i do to optimize this?

edit: link to the sppech module https://pypi.python.org/pypi/speech/0.5.2

edit2: per request i measured the sleep time only using datetime. 
2016-06-29 18:39:42.953000
2016-06-29 18:39:43.954000
i found that it was pretty accurate

edit3: i tried the build in import win32com.client and it didnt work either

```
import speech
import time
import os 

def exercise1():
    speech.say("exercise1")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    for n in range(0, rep*2):
        speech.say("1")
        t   ime.sleep(1)
        speech.say("2")
        time.sleep(1)
        speech.say("3")
        time.sleep(1)
        speech.say("switch")
```

Comment: capture the system time before/after the say() calls. you'll probably find taht sleep is pretty much exactly 1 second, and the say() call is the one with the variable duration.

Comment: can you hint me how to do that and yeah i think you are correct
edit: 
i got this:
2016-06-29 18:39:42.953000
2016-06-29 18:39:43.954000

so almost perfectly 1 second how do i go about fixing the speech then?

Answer (score 0):

Refer the post here [How accurate is python's time.sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133857/how-accurate-is-pythons-time-sleep)

It says:

> "The accuracy of the time.sleep function depends on the accuracy of
>   your underlying OS's sleep accuracy. For non-realtime OS's like a
>   stock Windows the smallest interval you can sleep for is about
>   10-13ms. I have seen accurate sleeps within several milliseconds of
>   that time when above the minimum 10-13ms."

Comment: because of the other guy recomendation i did try to measusre the sleep time to find that it is pretty accurate 1 second

Answer (score 0):

As you say in the comments, sleep(1) is fairly accurately 1s.

What you want to do to make each part take 1s, is time the "say" call, and then wait the remaining time to fill out the second. Something like this:

```
start = time.time()
speech.say("whatever")
end = time.time()
sleep(1 - (end - start)) # Wait however long will bring the time up to 1 second total
```

Comment: ty i havent thought about that actually it still isnt going to match but ty i think this is the best its gonna be

Comment: @rasmus393 If an answer was helpful or solved your problem, I'd encourage you to accept it (not necessarily mine!)

Comment: is it fine it is just helpfull or does it have to solve my problem. not being cheeky

Comment: because i tried doing this 


`def exercise1():
 speaker.Speak("exercise1")
 time.sleep(0.5)
 for n in range(0, rep*2):
  start = time.time()
  speech.say("1")
  end = time.time()
  time.sleep(1 - (start - end))
  start = time.time()
  speech.say("2")`

and now it takes even longer i guess because there is more to prosses

Comment: @rasmus393 ah, I had a typo, it should actually be `end - start`, that explains why it's taking longer

Comment: now I have tried this 'start = time.time()
  speech.say("1")
  end = time.time()
  time.sleep(1 - (end - start))
  start = time.time()
  speech.say("2")
  end = time.time()
  time.sleep(1 - (end - start))'

and it just stoops like it is sleeping forever