# On Windows python wakes up too early

Tags: python, time, profiling, sleep

```
from time import clock, sleep

for i in range(100):
    t1 = clock()
    sleep(0.123)
    t2 = clock()
    print(t2-t1)
```

[image]

Why are most of the timings below 0.123?

On unix (using `time.time()` instead of `time.clock()` as suggested in the manuals), all times are above 0.123 just as expected.

Comment: python 3.5.2 x64, windows 7 x64

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1133888/2016436) might give you some pointers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How accurate is python's time.sleep()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133857/how-accurate-is-pythons-time-sleep)

Comment: The Windows sleep function takes an integer count of milliseconds to sleep. Python's float needs to be converted to an integer and that conversion is not completely accurate.