# High precision sleep/delay in python (without interruption)

Tags: python, time, interrupt, gpio, wiringpi

I need to do some operations on Raspberry Pi3 pins in specific time. For example I send some bytes via uart then I need to wait about 5ms and again send next part of bytes, but I noticed that if I do `time.sleep(0.005)` or for example `wiringpi.delay(5)` from time to time this sleep/delay has some kind of interruption and it doesn't takes 5ms but for example 10ms. All this is irregular and I doesn't know how to catch this problem. Some ideas how to made that always 5ms ?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133857/how-accurate-is-pythons-time-sleep) out...

Comment: I saw this before

Comment: @coder this questions maybe are similar but in mine, main problem is that sleep/delay are giving me sometimes different time interval. So it works good for most of time and then gives me not 5ms but 10ms. As you see this have nothing to finding out accurating of `time.sleep` because Like I said before my problem is irregular.