# For X seconds do some action every Y seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I stumbled upon an answer that almost satisfies my question.

In my case I want to fetch the status of my limit buy order in market for 5 seconds every 0.8 seconds or so. The code that I found looks like this:

```
import threading

def printit():
  threading.Timer(0.8, printit).start()
  print("Hello, World!")
```

and to run something for 5 seconds, one can do the following:

```
import time
  t_end = time.time() + 5
  while time.time() < t_end:
    print('Hello World')
```

but combining those two like so, is not gonna work:

```
while time.time() < t_end:
  printit()
```

So I am just wondering how I can make printit() run every 0.8 seconds for 5 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go! just put your function call where I am printing!

```
import time
totalTime = 5
dt = 0.0

while dt <= totalTime:
    print(dt)
    time.sleep(0.8)
    dt += 0.8
```

Comment: Not a very robust solution, since `time.sleep` is not precise. This will almost assuredly take over 6 seconds to finish (especially because you're sleeping for another interval on the last time around). It's a great quick solution for a console app, though.

Comment: @AdamSmith he did say "0.8 seconds or so"

Comment: for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133857/how-accurate-is-pythons-time-sleep

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal Note that `sleep` will put your whole program to sleep for (at least) the specified interval. That may be ok, but if you don't want that to happen then you should use threading.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a variation of your threading code. The benefit of using threading is that the whole program isn't frozen, so you can (for example) fetch some data from a URL while you're waiting, rather than having a fetch-sleep cycle.

```
import threading
import time

def printit(interval, endtime):
    now = time.time()
    if now < endtime:
        threading.Timer(interval, printit, args=[interval, endtime]).start()
        print("Hello", now - t_start)

t_start = time.time()

printit(0.8, t_start + 5)
```

**typical output**

```
Hello 4.458427429199219e-05
Hello 0.8010139465332031
Hello 1.6028234958648682
Hello 2.4049606323242188
Hello 3.205900192260742
Hello 4.0072197914123535
Hello 4.808593988418579
```

Comment: I'd love to see this using async coroutines. I might play with that over my lunch, I haven't done much with async/await yet.

Comment: Great Answer @PM 2Ring

Comment: @AdamSmith I had a little look at async last year, but I've forgotten almost everything I learned. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring I remember looking at it, scoffing indignantly and thinking "Well if I wanted to do this, I'd write it in Go." Oh how *proud* of myself I still was, then... :)