# Python serial - reading time inconsistency

Tags: python, time, serial-port

I'm  trying on my PC (Windows10) to read data from another device which is connected through USB at 115200 baud rate with Python. I would like to reach bytes one by one, so I'm using `serial.read()` function.
I wanted to check the program performance using `time`, and I have seen reading times inconsistency occuring each 64th value that is beeing read. The time taken at this specific step is 50 to 100 higher than other values, making the program slow and cause data loss sometime...

After some research, I thought it was due to the `append` function implementation according to the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57248652/why-is-there-inconsistency-in-resolution-of-pythons-time-functions-such-as-per) but it didn't solve my problem.
I believe that the problem comes from the `read()` function but I can't understand why it is occuring.

Here is my code :

```
import serial
import time

counter_max = 24*100
test_mode = 0

PORT = 'COM12'
BAUDRATE = 115200
uart_port = serial.Serial()
uart_port.port = PORT
uart_port.baudrate = BAUDRATE
uart_port.timeout = None
uart_port.open()

counter = 0

if test_mode == 0:
# --- LIST VERSION -----------------------------------------------------------

    elapsed_times = []
    uart_datas = []
    
    while counter < counter_max:
        time_start = time.perf_counter_ns()
         
        uart_data = uart_port.read()
        uart_datas.append(uart_data)
        
        time_stop = time.perf_counter_ns()
        elapsed = time_stop - time_start
        elapsed_times.append(elapsed)
    
        counter += 1    

elif test_mode == 1:
# --- PREALOCATTED LIST VERSION ----------------------------------------------
    
    elapsed_times = [None] * (counter_max)
    uart_datas = [None] * (counter_max)
    
    while counter < counter_max:    
    
        time_start = time.perf_counter_ns()
    
        uart_data = uart_port.read()
        uart_datas[counter] = uart_data
        
        time_stop = time.perf_counter_ns()
        elapsed = time_stop - time_start
        elapsed_times[counter] = elapsed
    
        counter += 1    

uart_port.close()
# print(elapsed_times)
```

Any help to understand why it is happening, and how I could avoid it, would be much appreciated ! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated, you are using a microcontroller, so first step is to check that the data rate is actually as you expect it to be.  Use an oscilloscope or - even better - a logic analyzer to make sure that you don't have gaps that are 50-100 times higher and make sure that you are definitely sending the data as you expect.

Every time you call `read()` method, python has to go to the OS, OS goes to any software buffers, and there may or may not be hardware buffers.  Every 64th byte is interesting... there may be a 64-byte buffer that represents a cache-miss or some equivalent.  I suspect that you will continue to experience this so long as you are reading one byte at a time.

A better solution would be to read all data that is available and parse it sequentially - if that is what you want to do.

```
byte_counts = []
elapsed_times = []
uart_datas = []

while counter < counter_max:
    time_start = time.perf_counter_ns()
     
    uart_data = uart_port.read(uart_port.in_waiting)
    uart_datas += uart_data
    byte_counts.append(byte_counts)
    
    time_stop = time.perf_counter_ns()
    elapsed = time_stop - time_start
    elapsed_times.append(elapsed)

    counter += 1

# check here to see how many bytes you received between
# while loops by inspecting the `byte_counts` list; it is
# possible that you are reading 1 byte at a time when there
# are hundreds or even thousands available; also possible
# that there are none sometimes
```

Any interaction between python code and OS code will almost certainly involve buffers of some sort.  Buffers don't like to be read one at a time and the strange behavior every 64th byte could be an indicator of physical or compiled buffer alignment.  In theory, this shouldn't be too much of a problem, just very much slows your program down.

Your indication that you are missing data is more interesting.  If you have confirmed that your microcontroller is definitely sending all data, then this could be an indicator of some buffer overrun.  By reading all available data from the OS, you should be clearing the data frequently enough that this shouldn't be a factor.

I suspect that this won't completely solve your problem, but it will help you architect your program to be more performant and work better with hardware.  Good luck,

j

Comment: Your answer has fully solved the 'how I can avoid it' and gave me an insight into the 'why'. I have checked the data transmission with a logic analyzer and everything is fine. I have tried the code on macOS and I can't reproduce the problem, so this is definitely related to how the OS is handling the `read()` function. As you said there  must be an underlying buffer implementation. I have also tried your code and it works like a charm ! Thanks for the advice