# How would I be able to make a delay in python for a few nano seconds?

Tags: python, delay

I would like to make a program which will run on a raspberry pi, that will switch on a circuit, and switch another circuit on a few nano seconds afterwards. Is it possible to create a delay that is so small?

Comment: No, not directly in python. You may struggle to do that in C++ on an rpi.

Comment: If you need that kind of precision, I wonder why you're using python in the first place

Comment: Measure how fast Python is on that Raspberry when running normal code. Is it accurate in a nanoseconds range?

Comment: See this: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3898/nanosleep-wont-sleep-short-time?newreg=09230bb9224b48c4b3ab8d3f4c5765f0.

Comment: OK, but is it possible to get a delay smaller than a millisecond? (0.001 seconds)?

Comment: Just a side info: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1133857/2648551 and https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0564/

Comment: You'll have to test if your Raspberry supports [getting nanosecond timings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter).

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this -

```
start = time.time()
while time.time() - start < 0.15:
     pass
```

you can create a delay and use the same.

Answer (score -1):

```
import time
delay = 0.001 #seconds
time.sleep(delay)
```

Comment: Just for refererence, even if it were possible, 1 nanosecond is 0.000000001 seconds, not 0.001...