# More precise sleep (usleep) in Python?

Tags: python, synchronization, usleep

I'm trying to implement real-time plotting in Python, with samples being around 500-1000 microseconds apart. Using `time.sleep()` between drawing each sample doesn't work due to reasons mentioned here: [accuracy of sleep()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133857/how-accurate-is-pythons-time-sleep). I'm currently doing busy waiting like this:

```
stime = time()
while stime + diff/1000000 > time():
    pass
```

But it's taking a lot of CPU resources and it's also not 100% precise. Is there a better way of doing this (preferably platform independent and not busy waiting)?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just call [`usleep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#finding-shared-libraries) directly:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes.util import find_library

libc = find_library('c')

libc.usleep(1)
```

This should work on Linux or Mac.