# time.sleep() not working properly in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, sleep

There seems to be some sort of cap for time.sleep() that is stopping my "pong" game from increasing speed appropriately.

```
game_is_on = True
while game_is_on:
    time.sleep(ball.move_speed)
    screen.update()
    ball.move()
```

where move_speed is reduced by 20% after every such-and-such occurrence.

I've tested it by removing ball.move_speed and instead used 0.1, then 0.01, both of which worked, but when I try 0.001 or lower, it doesn't get any faster.

Comment: Which operating system? On linux I think the resolution is 1 millisecond.

Comment: Does it work outside PyCharm? It might be an issue with the way the PyCharm console buffers output.

Comment: Some good information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133857/how-accurate-is-pythons-time-sleep) about sub-second `sleep()`.

Comment: Sorry I'm noob and don't know how to respond to individual comments.
I'm on windows.
I haven't actually tried it outside of PyCharm, I'll look into it!

Comment: To respond to an individual use for instance @tdelaney.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a [mcve], then it will be possible to assist you. Which libraries are you using?