# Parallel programming: Synchronizing processes

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, synchronization

I have a program which has a lot of music decks (deck 1, deck 2, music_clip_deck, speackers_deck, ip_call_1, ip_call_2, ip_call_3). Each deck works in a seperate process. The chunk time I use to crop the mp3 files/retransmitions stream/voice from microphone/voice from aiortc-pyav is 125msec. After that I fill some queues (one for each seperate process) and I send the final queue to the final thread for the final audio processing before hearing and transmitted to clients.

How can I synchronize all the process together, so one while run time of each process takes exactly 125 msec?

Here is one figure for help:

[image]

This approach may not help at all:

```py
class Deck_1_Proc(Process):
...
...
...
    def run(self):
        while(True):
            t1 = time.time()
            ...
            ...
            ...
            t2 = time.time()
            if t2 - t1 < 0.125:
                time.sleep(0.125 - (t2 - t1))
```

Maybe a better approach should be use something like javascript setInterval with time parameter: 125msec

```py
from threading import Event, Thread

def call_repeatedly(interval, func, *args):
    stopped = Event()
    def loop():
        while not stopped.wait(interval): # the first call is in `interval` secs
            func(*args)
    Thread(target=loop).start()    
    return stopped.set

#call:
cancel_future_calls = call_repeatedly(0.125, run)
#stopping to app termination:
cancel_future_calls()
```

Comment: I can tell you that *exactly 125ms.* cannot be assured since you have no control over when a process or thread gets suspended and resumed (also the clock resolution with `time.time()` is not adequate). But I am missing the fundamental point of all of this because the code you have posted is either too minimal or I am too ignorant. Is it that even if the task completes before 125ms it must it must then pause before it does something with its result (such as writing it to a queue). If you are looking to throttle a function call, that is rather easy to do.

Comment: I was under the impression that the threading library didn't allow for real concurrency in CPython? (unless OP isn't working in CPython)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the main issue is that most timers drift, and `sleep` [is not accurate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1133888/15649230), [not even QTimer](https://forum.qt.io/topic/57280/longtime-stability-of-qtimer-events/5), so a stable timer (in a sense that the 100th tick is close to 12.5 seconds) would have to do something like this.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Condition
def infinite_heartbreat(cv: Condition):
    next_beat = time.time()
    while True:
        next_beat += 0.125
        time_to_sleep = next_beat - time.time()
        if time_to_sleep > 0:
            time.sleep(time_to_sleep)
        with cv:
            cv.notify_all()
```

you can easily synchronize all processes to wake up at the same time using a [Condition Variable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Condition), but if one of them lags behind for a few milliseconds you probably need a [multiprocessing.Value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) to ensure they only wait if they are not lagging behind as follows:

```
import threading
import time
from multiprocessing import Condition, Value, Process, Event
def infinite_heartbreat(cv: Condition, frame: Value, quit_event: Event):
    next_beat = time.time()
    while True:
        next_beat += 0.125
        time_to_sleep = next_beat - time.time()
        if time_to_sleep > 0:
            time.sleep(time_to_sleep)
        with cv:
            frame.value += 1
            cv.notify_all()
            if quit_event.is_set():
                return

def worker(cv, frame_number, worker_id, quit_event: Event):
    current_frame = 0
    while True:
        with cv:
            cv.wait_for(lambda: current_frame <= frame_number.value)
            if quit_event.is_set():
                return
        print(f"processed frame {current_frame} in worker {worker_id}")
        current_frame += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    condition = Condition()
    frame = Value('q', lock=False)
    quit_event = Event()
    processes = []
    for i in range(4):
        process = Process(target=worker, args=(condition, frame, i, quit_event))
        process.start()
        processes.append(process)
    tr = threading.Thread(target=infinite_heartbreat, args=(condition,frame, quit_event))
    tr.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    quit_event.set()
```

Edit: added a `quit_event` in the form of a [multiprocessing.Event](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Event), because it is an atomic.

Edit2: changed the value to be signed `q` with no lock, as per @Booboo comment, this saves a file descriptor and allows negative frame numbers (as -1 has its uses).

Comment: Nice question, it seems that with this approach, we made a new event loop (looks a lot like). Thanks! But how should i stop the proccesses?

Comment: @ChrisP i have updated the answer with a `quit_event` for that, the only note is that you should always check the event under the `Condition` mutex, to prevent race conditions, if you instead wanted a pause and resume functionality then you need another event but you have to check it inside the mutex then wait for it outside the mutex.

Comment: You can get by with `frame = Value('Q', Lock=False)`. Also, using a type code of `Q` (unsigned 8-byte value) might be a bit overkill. At one heartbeat every .125 seconds your frame number can be correctly incrementing without wrapping around for 2.305843009213694e+18 seconds. The universe is only 4.36117077e+17 seconds old. :-)

Comment: I have one lissue here: deck_1_process sometimes plays from web-radio-stream-url. It uses Popen to download the stream file using ffmpeg. Then there is a `while(download_file_exists)` loop. This loop takes 8 sec to break. After that the one-loop deck_1_process returns. but then there are quickly runs without sync sleep to cause the current_duration to get into 8 seconds. Any idea how can i solve this? There is no error in final_slice, final_slice_plot, final_slice_pyaudio processes but there is 8*1000/125 quickly runs one after another in deck_1_process.

Comment: If found a solution to this: I just return AudioSegment.empty() when the ffmpeg retransmition file doesn't exists.